# How to provide updateMask during Google People update contact?

Tags: google-people-api

If I need to update the name or address of a contact, giving the field as "names, addresses" works.

How do I need to give the updateMask to update a specific field like "middleName" alone.

Providing updateMask as "names.middleName" does not work and throws the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid updatePersonFields mask path: \"names.middle_name\". Valid paths are documented at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Can you show your request?

Comment: Doesn't work even in the "Try this API" section.
updatePersonFields = names.middleName

`{
  "names": [
    {
      "middleName": "middle name change"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "etag_value"
}`

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `names` as `updatePersonFields`, but all names need to be specified. This may be a bug, as linked below, but it is also not clear from the documentation.*

#### More Information:

It is possible this is a bug, though until a response is obtained from the [issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/190526979) (which I assume was you -but if not - hit the star to help it gain more attention) about this it is not possible to know for sure.

While `FieldMask`s *do* accept sub-fields, these are not specified on the `updatePersonFields` documentation page, only the broader `names`.

You can see the list of definitely supported fields [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#query-parameters) under the Query Parameters.

#### Current Workaround:

While waiting for Google to respond to the bug report, the only way you can get around this is by using the `names` field mask, but also including the `firstName` and `lastName` parameters too when making the patch:

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "givenName": "Rafa",
      "middleName": "Guillermo",
      "familyName": "Rocks"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "%XxXXXx00XxxXXXXXXxXXXX00XXXXXXxXxxX0"
}
```

**Remember:** If you leave out any of these fields this is tantamount to replacing it with empty string - so be careful!

Comment: But the updateMask is mentioned as string ([FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) format). FieldMask format supports sub-fields.

Suppose I have prefix, suffix and middleName in my Name object. Considering the case where I just need to update middleName, just adding middle name to the name object when updating erases my prefix and suffix field. Similar cases for all the other fields like address etc.

Comment: Looking into this... it's possibly a bug. Hopefully that Issue Trakcer report will get a response soon. In the mean time you'll have to update all three each time and just use the `names` field mask - I've updated my answer to reflect this information.

Comment: Yes I had filed the issue tracker report. Will inform here if I get any response from Google!

Comment: Feature request available here: https://issuetracker.google.com/190526979